# Email notification or several reminders at different time points

Tags: rules

I have content where in I have to send the email notification or several reminders at different time points:
Ex: After saving content, email should send after 1month. 
then after 6 months for the same content.
then once every 5 years.
I have tried with node expiry module but it displays content expiry, and when we run the cron at that time only its able to send the mail,user cant run the cron every time sometime he may forget though.

Also I tried with rules schedule but I am not getting exactly what I want like i cant send the email according to time interval, also how to send mail without running the cron. can any one know how to resolve this issue.please help me.

Comment: Can you enhance (edit) your question please to provide more details about the "... but I am not getting exactly what I want ...".

Comment: All the solutions to this are going to require cron to be run.  You should be running cron on some sort of regular schedule anyway, so that should not be considered a negative.  If you don't know how to set up cron properly on your server, you can have it triggered automatically via page requests by visiting admin/config/system/cron and choosing an option for "Run cron every" there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rules and [scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module which is work with rule to send mail at period of time.

Comment: I tried with scheduler when i check in the scheduled nodes it displays "There are no scheduled nodes" though i followed http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webwash.net%2Ftutorials%2Fhow-send-follow-emails-using-rules-scheduler-drupal-7&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNE5puoLMAWl93ewNYCAwI1twRhlcg

Comment: 1. Create a rule set that sends an email to a user. (The user should be provided as an argument to the rule set.)
2. Create a triggered rule that is triggered when a user logs in
3. Let the triggered rule execute an action 'Schedule name-of-your-email-rule-set'. Set the time of evaluation to '+ 7 days'.

Comment: Its tricky but cab ne possible.